# How to know if a image is completely uploaded to a server before creating its thumbnail?

Tags: php

I have script that create image gallery automatically from a folder. It also generates thumbnails if it doesn't exist. Everything works finely except a particular situation. thumbnail generation is invoked by user accessing the page (Psudo CRON).

I was trying to download a image to the folder of gallery in my server using **wget** (A big image) and at the same time some one accessed the web page and thumbnail was generated from the partial downloaded image, which created a partial thumbnail like below.

[image: Partially generated thumbnail]

To fix this before creating thumbnail I started to check file last modification time and modification time after 600 micro second. if they are different I will skip the image thumbnail generation. This should work if the upload is not stuck anywhere and file is being constantly updated. But on other hand it will fail if the upload is not updating file in specified time interval

My code

```
//loop
$atime = filemtime($images_dir . $file);
usleep(600);
$btime = filemtime($images_dir . $file);
/* file uploading checking */
if ($atime != $btime) {
    continue;
}
// code to generate the thumbnail
```

Is there any other way to solve this issue ?

Please note here user has direct access to folder and he can populate it any way using ftp/another script etc, that is uploading is not controlled by script.

Comment: You may want to look into using NodeJS instead of PHP.  My company is making the switch now and it really helps accomplish stuff like this.  The fact that you can do full duplex between client and server is amazing.

Comment: What about saving the image as `blah.png.temp` and then rename it so `blah.png` once it's done uploading. That way the file won't be available until it is fully uploaded.

Comment: Actually uploading is not controlled by any script, so I don't have that freedom to rename file or move file. And this is going to be part of wordpress plugin so can't think about a cron job too. 
I was wondering if there any way to compare file size from header and current size

Comment: Why don't you code so that the script processes files if they were modified at least _x_ minutes ago. You can be somewhat sure that the file is not being modified anymore.

Comment: @SalmanA this worked ! thanks, but still this isnt a proper way so I guess I will leave the question opened. Consider a situation where updation is critical, like within seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Solution seems pretty simple to me. Don't put the images in your upload directory until the process of downloading the image is complete. You move them into the directory after they're on your filesystem.

Comment: Not that simple in this situation here person has direct access to folder and he uploads it using ftp, or download images using wget or use any other script to populate the folder, so this doesn’t work in my situation as uploads are not completed.

Comment: Sorry the situation here uploads are not controlled by script, so there is no way to implement this, as i have mentioned ftp/wget is used to populate folder

Comment: @RohithRaveendran I don't get why this is an issue still? Whether or not the files are dropped there by script or uploaded via FTP, you can  even write a cron-job that scans the directory on every X (whatever interval you feel is appropriate) and find files that haven't been modified in the last 10 minutes. Then move them into your uploads directory. The implementation may be slightly different, but the idea is the same.